# Start and finish date of each week of the year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, week-number

I am trying to display on a page each week of the years start and finish date so like below

```
Week 1 - 1/1/2015 - 7/1/2015  
Week 2 - 8/1/2015 - 14/1/2015
```

and so forth is there any way to achieve this my end result will be displaying how many leads have been entered into our CRM for each week of the year so like

```
week 1 50 leads  
week 2 10 leads
```

table structure can be found here
http://jsfiddle.net/prac85yx/

Comment: Take care: week number 1 of 2015 starts 29/12/2014

Comment: yep i gathered that just wanted to clarify it easier

Comment: @Nathan Week 2 end on 14th Jan not 16th  Jan. Am I correct?

Comment: yes i didn't add the correct dates in there i probably should have now that i think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(lead_date, '%d/%c/%Y')) leadYear, 
       CEILING(DAYOFYEAR(STR_TO_DATE(lead_date, '%d/%c/%Y')) / 7) AS WeekNo, 
       COUNT(lead_idno) AS leadCount
FROM tbl_contacts 
GROUP BY leadYear, WeekNo;
```

Comment: just tried this and doesn't show any results `SELECT CEILING(DAYOFYEAR(`lead_date`) / 7) AS WeekNo, COUNT(`lead_idno`) AS leadCount FROM tbl_contacts GROUP BY WeekNo`

Comment: yes mysql and no error in the query im running the command in phpmyadmin

Comment: cant seem to work out how to use the mysql fiddle keeps giving me all these answers

Comment: @Nathan Then just add sample data in table format in your question

Comment: for me it comes up as leadyear null weekno null leadcount 54 when i run this in phpmyadmin

Comment: the date is stored as varchar

Comment: how can i now get that to display on a page as in the php code to display it :-)

Comment: just need to display the results like they are year week leads im unsure how to display leadYear and weekNo as there not row names

Comment: was chasing this :-) `$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(lead_date, '%d/%c/%Y')) leadYear, CEILING(DAYOFYEAR(STR_TO_DATE(lead_date, '%d/%c/%Y')) / 7) AS WeekNo, COUNT(lead_idno) AS leadCount FROM tbl_contacts GROUP BY leadYear, WeekNo");
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
   {  
    echo $row2['leadYear'] . " " . $row2['WeekNo'] . " " .$row2['leadCount'] . "<br>" ; 
       
    
   }`

Comment: thanks for all our your help and taking the time to help me out :-)